# NSXML Parser Image URL Inside CDATA Block

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I try to load a attributed element. In this post is a lot of code to show what I have and clear (hopefully) all questions.

**Parser.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Parser : NSXMLParser

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *rowElementName; // this is the element name that identifies a new row of data in the XML
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *attributeNames;  // this is the array of attributes we might want to retrieve for that element name
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *elementNames;    // this is the list of sub element names for which we're retrieving values

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;    // after parsing, this is the array of parsed items
@end
```

**Parser.m**

```
#import "Parser.h"

@interface Parser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *item;     // while parsing, this is the item currently being parsed
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *elementValue; // this is the element within that item being parsed

@end

@implementation Parser

- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url{
    self = [super initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if (self){
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data{
    self = [super initWithData:data];
    if (self){
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStream:(NSInputStream *)stream{
    self = [super initWithStream:stream];

    if (self){
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate methods

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (!self.rowElementName)
        NSLog(@"%s Warning: Failed to specify row identifier element name", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:self.rowElementName]){
        self.item  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (NSString *attributeName in self.attributeNames){
            id attributeValue = [attributeDict valueForKey:attributeName];
            if (attributeValue)
                [self.item setObject:attributeValue forKey:attributeName];
        }
    }
    else if ([self.elementNames containsObject:elementName]){
        self.elementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if (self.elementValue){
        [self.elementValue appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:self.rowElementName]){
        [self.items addObject:self.item];
        self.item = nil;
    }
    else if ([self.elementNames containsObject:elementName]){
        [self.item setValue:self.elementValue forKey:elementName];
        self.elementValue = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

**XML structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name><![CDATA[FooName]]></name>
        <Snippet><![CDATA[FooSniped]]></Snippet>
        <description><![CDATA[<img src="http://www.foosite.com/fooimage.jpg">FooDescription]]></description>
    </Placemark> </Document>
```

Now to my real question. I have no problem to parse all the Informations out with the usual tags like  but I cannot get the Image URL out of the description. i do the usual way: 
`parser.attributeNames = @[@"src"];` 
but it return `(null)` so I think there is something wrong. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am using this simple lines:

```
Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser.rowElementName = @"Placemark";
parser.elementNames = @[@"name", @"Snippet", @"description"];
parser.attributeNames = @[@"src"]; //return (null)
[parser parse];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using CDATA delegate method of the NSXMLParser class:

First of all you need to use the "foundCData" delegate method. It will help you to get the image url out of CDATA blocks in the web service you are parsing.

```
  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock {


    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [elementValue appendString:someString];

    NSString *imageURLString = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];
}
```

Below is the method that your are calling from the CDATA method to get the image url string:

```
-(NSString *)getFirstImageUrl: (NSString *) html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *imageURL = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: html];

    // find start of tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString: @"<img" intoString: NULL];
    if ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString: @"src=\"" intoString: NULL];
        NSInteger newLoc2 = [theScanner scanLocation] + 5;
        [theScanner setScanLocation: newLoc2];

        // find end of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString: @"\"" intoString: &imageURL];
    }

    return imageURL;
}
```

Once you have the url of the images, you can use it to download them and show where ever you want in your app

Comment: and what is the best way to use it? NSXML is not my strong point.

Comment: it's look like tedious because i need only 5 lines of code for 4 keywords. I'm looking for a better way. In that case I don't get your code to work.